# remove a sub array from an array by condition

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to remove a subarray from an array based on its element, e.g. if it contains the value `"TOTO"` (in a variable) for the key `"ppd name"`

My array is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => R419FD00Customers1556106426
            [main] => Array
                (
                    [release] => R419
                    [delivery] => FD00
                    [upgrade Type] => Customers
                    [upgrade date] => 2019-04-11
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => R422Beta1internal1556107476
            [main] => Array
                (
                    [release] => R422
                    [delivery] => Beta1
                    [upgrade Type] => internal
                    [upgrade date] => 2019-04-10
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ppd name] => TOTO
                    [start clone] => 2019-04-24
                    [ppd delivery] => 2019-04-18
                    [target evenement] => lastBuild
                    [target date] => 2019-04-18
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ppd name] => TITI
                    [start clone] => 2019-04-05
                    [ppd delivery] => 2019-04-05
                    [target evenement] => lastBuild
                    [target date] => 2019-04-04
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => R420FD03Customers1556110346
            [main] => Array
                (
                    [release] => R420
                    [delivery] => FD03
                    [upgrade Type] => Customers
                    [upgrade date] => 2019-04-24
                )

        )

)
```

I tried

```
foreach ($arr_data as $Array) {
    foreach($Array as $subKey => $subArray) {
        if ($subArray['ppd name'] == 'TOTO') {
            unset($arr_data[$subKey]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You realise you need to use a loop, so how far have you got so far?

Comment: I tried that
foreach($arr_data as $Array){
      foreach($Array as $subKey => $subArray){
       if($subArray['ppd name'] == 'TOTO'){
           unset($arr_data[$subKey]);
       }
      }
     }

Comment: Do you want to remove only the subarray (with key 0) or the parent array (with key 2)?

Comment: added authors example from comment, removed duplicate requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_walk`, `foreach` to remove the desired element

```
$search = 'TOTO';
array_walk($arr, function($value, $key) use (&$arr, $search){
    foreach($value as $k => $v){
        if(isset($v['ppd name']) && $v['ppd name'] == $search){

            unset($arr[$key][$k]);
        }
    }
});
```